# $(document).on() multiple specific events

Tags: jquery

I want to use $(document).on(), but I only want it to apply to 2 very specific events.

The events are when a form is submitted, or when a button is clicked. Both of these elements will have a data-ajax attribute.

To give you an idea what I need, here is code I tried which did not work:

```
$(document).on('form[data-ajax]:submit, button[data-ajax]:click', function (event) {
    alert('do stuff');
}
```

How do I get this to work for these very specific events?

Comment: what is the value of data-ajax?i think it should be `$(document).on('click','input[data-ajax=valuehere], button[data-ajax=valuehere]', function (event) {`

Comment: You need to chain them as separate events.

Comment: @ShaunakD I am beginning to think that is my only choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function and call the function whenever each event fires like so:

```
function fireThisUponEvent( event ) {
    //your code goes here
}

$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-ajax]', fireThisUponEvent);

$(document).on('click', 'button[data-ajax]', fireThisUponEvent);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
$(document).on('submit click','form[data-ajax] , button[data-ajax]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('do stuff');
});
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hm4ph1sr/1/)

Comment: The problem with this is that it fires when you click anything inside a form with the data-ajax attribute.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
// e.type is the type of event fired
 });
```